# How can I convert exited sql date?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am new in c#

I have a column in my fill sql database that has string format but i have two kind value data format there like this:

`Jul 29 2014 12:00AM`

and

`11/11/2014`

How can I convert all `Jul 29 2014 12:00AM` value to `11/11/2014` value?

Comment: Use the [correct data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)(`datetime`) in the first place.

Comment: Don't store dates as strings, store them as dates. Moreover, don't *assume* what the string format is, specify it explicitly. Is i`11/11` November 11 or 11 November? Outside the implied format is `11 November`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
        String stringDate="Jul 29 2014 12:00AM";
        DateTime date=DateTime.Parse(stringDate);
        Console.Write(date.ToString());
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/GFxhz2)

If you wanna to change in query

```
SELECT convert(datetime, 'Jul 29 2014 12:00AM', 101)
```

Comment: There is no guaranteed to `DateTime.Parse` method parses this string successfully. And I don't understand why this answer selected as an answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of that test case where `DateTime.Parse` will fall as user say that his all data are inserted in database formate like  `Jul 29 2014 12:00AM`. as far my logic say this format inserted from a datetime variable.

Comment: This is guaranteed to fail in any **client-side** culture other than US. It could be made to work if you pass the CultureInfo that matches the string format stored in the database, which in this case seems to be `en-US`.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi `DateTime.Parse` uses `CurrentCulture` by default. That means, if your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:sstt` as a standard date and time format, your parsing operation will fail.

Comment: Adding to @SonerGönül in a web-site CurrentCulture may be controlled by the end user's browser settings, while in a desktop application it's controlled by the user's locale. You need to know the locale used when the date strings were stored. If the strings were created at the client side, this will depend on the writer's locale.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't do that!

A [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) doesn't have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. There is no such a thing like;

> A DateTime with `Jul 29 2014 12:00AM` or `11/11/2014` format.

String representations of a `DateTime` can have format. In such a case, `Jul 29 2014 12:00AM` will be just database management system representation of your `DateTime`

If you keep your dates in a character column, stop it! Change your column type to `datetime` or a related type.

If you just want to represent your `DateTime` with a specific format, use `.ToString()` like;

```
date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And please read;

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

```
.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

use this behind an date variable and it format to month/day/year.

Comment: This will only work if dates were stored in US format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos A `DateTime` doesn't have _any_ implicit format. There is no such a thing called: _dates were stored in US format_

Comment: @SonerGönül Which is exactly my point. The OP says he has dates stored as strings in both long and short date formats, but this answer assumes these *strings* are in a US-only short date format. A mess that can only be fixed by storing dates as dates

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly. The root problem is saving dates as a string which is **always a bad idea**.